# EC2 Instance Freezes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, celery

I am facing sudden freezes in one of my instances.

Here are some details about the instance:

```
Type: t2.micro
Region: ap-southeast-1
Platform: Ubuntu
Platform details: Linux/UNIX
```

I have two apps running on this instance, and also I have a celery service working there.
these freezes start to happen since I run the celery service.

I am not really sure how to find and trace the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "freeze" mean? Are you not able to connect to the instance with SSH? Are you not able to ping the instance? Or is it just that the applications that you're running don't make progress (which is extremely likely with a `t2.micro` running lots off apps).

Comment: @Parsifal yes, I'm not able to connect to the instance with ssh, and if I'm in the instance itself, nothing works, and I'm not able to run any commands. and also the applications stop working too. I have to reboot the instance from AWS console.

Comment: Hi, please how do you fix this? I'm currently facing same issue, instance get freezed because I'm using a GUI, now I can't even ssh into the instance. Stopping and restarting the instance doesn't help

Comment: @Mab my ec2 instance was getting frozen because of running out of memory. I had celery running on that instance and sometimes the memory was not enough. another problem that I had was there were too many not optimized local database(mongodb) queries, that I had to move to mongo atlas. for your case first, check if the post 22 is open(you can find it under the security group section on the ec2 dashboard)

Comment: @Nasrin thanks for your reply. Whenever my node js process run out of memory, the kernel simply kills the process, straightforward and no freezing. But when I installed GUI, after I open a tab in Chrome desktop, it freezes and the instance stop responding. I kill my VNC client and force stop the terminal but I'm not able to ssh into the instance again.                                Regarding the security group, I didn't create any new security group, it's the default ones and I think post 22 i.e. SSH service port (inbound from all IP) is open

Answer (score 2):

When an EC2 instance freezes that is quite often due to it running out of memory. So what you can do is to enable memory metrics (there is a guide in the AWS documentation how to do it) on your EC2 Celery nodes, and next time this happens check memory utilisation to confirm that machine was out of memory when it froze.

Comment: Oh, all right. I'll do that to check memory then

Answer (score 0):

You instance probably has high memory usage (probably memory leak) or high CPU usage (we had also this case)

you can use the tool 'atop' to monitor your CPU, Memory resources. This tool gives historical data of which process was utilizing maximum resources For more information, please refer the below links :

[+] https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-install-atop-to-monitor-logging-activity-of-linux-system-processes/
[+] https://haydenjames.io/use-atop-linux-server-performance-analysis/

You have mentioned that the issue gets resolved on rebooting the instance. It might be possible that memory crunch is happening on the instance. Rebooting the instance frees up the resources for sometime. However, as soon as the processes start coming up they may start consuming more resources making the instance unresponsive again and again.

I would recommend you to install(if already not installed) tools like atop, which will store the historical data of resource utilization and that will helps to find out more details like which process was consuming most of the resource etc and it will helps to troubleshoot the issue better. If based on atop logs you believe that your application requires more resources than offered by t2.micro then you may consider upgrading the instance type to one which offers more cpu/memory